# seq with timer to netcat

Tags: suspend, netcat, seq

I want to output sequential numbers every 100 ms into `nc -lk`. `seq 1 100 | nc -lk 9999` does output the numbers to nc but it doesn't have the timer. Is there any way to do it using `seq` and sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for x in {1..100}; do 
    echo $x | nc -lk 9999
    sleep 0.1 
done
```

Comment: +1. If the OP insist in using `seq` (although I don't see a reason), then `for x in $(seq 1 100); do` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Did this:

`for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 10); do echo $i; sleep 0.1; done | nc -lk 9999`